# How to implement a nanosecond resolution file access time stamp compatibility across multiple UNIX using the preprocessor

Tags: c, unix, c-preprocessor

Linux is implementing the [POSIX.1-2008](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) way; IBM AIX use[`long st_atime_n`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.files/stat.h.htm); NetBSD use[`long st_atimensec`](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/sys/stat.h?v=NETBSD); OpenBSD and Darwin use[`struct  timespec st_atimespec`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/stat.2.html).

All of them are member of`struct stat`. So how I can use the processor to see if a struct member name is defined?

Comment: Different header files have different constants defined. `#ifdef`ing them may be a way. If not this, you're the one who knows what is your code going to be compiled for, so just add a switch and a constant definition to your `configure` script.

Comment: @user35443 : this is a very small project of only two file, so I would like to avoid using auto-tools.

Comment: In that case you copy what's in the header files by hand. Find #ifdefs that identify all your possible builds.

Comment: @gnasher729 : But Apple and IBM doesn’t any #define for specifying their Operating systems.

Comment: Create your own ifdefs on your own macros (like `APPLE`, `NBDS`, `OBSD`), and compile using `-D`

Comment: @user35443 : yes but this means to tells users to do it manually.

Comment: If you want to avoid using "auto-tools", they'll always have to do it manually. That's what "auto-tools" are here for: automating a manual operation.

Comment: Sane people tell their kernel not to bother updating the "accessed time" attribute - it kills performance (every single time any file is read the kernel has to write to the disk to update the "accessed time").

Comment: @Brendan :  The question here is how to use the ones who does. But in that case most of them doesn’t follow the standard.

Comment: @user2284570: You'll find it's worse than that - some file systems (e.g. FAT, ISO9660) simply don't support it, any file system that is read-only can't support it; and there's no easy way to auto-detect if it's supported or not (because kernel might update it in its cache but not on disk). If you care about reliable software you don't rely on access time in the first place.

Comment: @user2284570: Also, I'm sure all these kernel follow "a standard". Whether that's the kernel's own standard or something completely broken like POSIX is a completely different matter. ;-)

Comment: @Brendan : if the filesystem doesn’t support it, it’s the task of the kernel to make the system call to work correctly *(I write the software with this feature because most server requires nanosecond resolution. If the filesystem doesn’t support it then it’s a user problem)*. The problem here is most kernels use there own`struct stat`for implementing the feature rather than the POSIX.1-2008 standard.